# Rails migration to change empty strings to null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration, rails-migrations

Say I have a db table called fruit like this:

```
id  name
1   ““
2   “"
3   ““
4   ““
5   ""
6   melon
```

I need to write a migration to change the empty strings to null without affecting `melon` in this case.

Would it be something on these lines?

```
def change
  update_column fruits, :name, null if :name => ""
end
```

Pretty basic stuff I guess but I'm kinda stuck here.
What is the best approach here?

Comment: why not just do an `update_all`, `Fruit.where(name: "").update_all(name: nil)`

Comment: @lusketeer you mean use that in the migration?

Comment: anywhere, rails console, migration, you don't really need a migration, but if want to keep things consistent, add it to migration

Comment: @lusketeer yeah consistency is the name of the game here :-), that worked a treat in a migration, throw it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fruit.where(name: "").update_all(name: nil)
```

rails console, migration, anywhere you can excute it. You don't really need a migration, but if want to keep things consistent, add it to migration

Answer (score 0):

in console development and production as well:

```
Fruit.all.each do |fruit|
  if fruit.name == ""
    fruit.name = nil
    fruit.save
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer a migration.

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal command to generate a migration;

```
rails g migration xxxxx
```

And then add:

```
def change
  execute "UPDATE fruits SET name = NULL WHERE name = '' "
end
```

Comment: in sql you use `name IS NULL`

Comment: i run the query with ( IS null ) in postgres , it gives error "syntax error at or near "IS" "

Comment: ok sorry, I misread your query, it sets `null` - it does not *search* for `null`

Comment: I won't upvote, since the answer is poorly formatted and not a great answer, but I removed my downvote.